# Count of set bits at an index in a given range

Tags: binary

I could not find any such query. Given a range and the index i, we want to count the numbers in the range that have bit i set.

Eg, range=[6,13] and i=2, ans=4

**6  0110**

**7  0111**

8  1000

9  1001

10 1010

11 1011

**12 1100**

**13 1101**

Is there a better approach than traversing the range